# Finding palindromes in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, palindrome

This is my first foray into OOP, so I'd appreciate any kind of advice!

Here is the problem description:

> On the first line of the input, you will receive a number specifying
>   how many lines of input to read. After that, the input consists of
>   some number of lines of text that you will read and determine whether
>   or not it is a palindrome.
>
> The only important factor in validating palindromes is whether or not
>   a sequence of letters is the same backwards and forwards. All other
>   types of characters (spaces, punctuation, newlines, etc.) should be
>   ignored, and whether a character is lower-case or upper-case is
>   irrelevant.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many lines will you be entering? ");
        int numberOfLines = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string mergedLine = MergeMultipleLinesIntoOneLine(numberOfLines);
        bool isPalindrome = IsPalindrome(mergedLine);
        Console.WriteLine(isPalindrome ? "Palindrome" : "Not a palindrome");
    }

    public static string MergeMultipleLinesIntoOneLine(int numberOfLines)
    {
        int line = 1;
        var stringResult = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter phrase #{0}: ", line);
            stringResult.Append(Console.ReadLine() + " ");
            line++;
        } while (line <= numberOfLines);

        return stringResult.ToString();
    }

    public static bool IsPalindrome(string someString)
    {
        string regexPattern = @"(?i)[^a-z]";
        string replacement = "";
        string amendedString = Regex.Replace(someString, regexPattern, replacement).ToLower();
        string reverseAmendedString = new string(amendedString.Reverse().ToArray());

        return amendedString.Equals(reverseAmendedString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use a `for` loop where fit**

```
public static string MergeMultipleLinesIntoOneLine(int numberOfLines)
{

    var stringResult = new StringBuilder();

    for (var line = 0; line < numberOfLines; line++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter phrase #{0}: ", line);
        stringResult.Append(Console.ReadLine() + " ");
    }

    return stringResult.ToString();
}
```

`MergeMultipleLinesIntoOneLine` was very weird, when looping a fixed number of times, you should always use a for loop.

**Refactor further**

`isPalindrome` does two things:

- It cleans the string.
- It actually checks if it a palindrome.

These are two things, so we need two functions:

```
public static string clean(string s) 
{
    string regexPattern = @"(?i)[^a-z]";
    string replacement = "";
    return Regex.Replace(s, regexPattern, replacement).ToLower();
}
```

and:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string someString)
{
    var amendedString = clean(someString);
    string reverseAmendedString = new string(amendedString.Reverse().ToArray());
    return amendedString.Equals(reverseAmendedString);
}
```

**Do not put types into the name of the variables.**

I am talking about `regexPattern`

**Use constants**

<strike>The cleaner Regex should be a class constant.</strike>

```
private const string cleaner = @"(?i)[^a-z]";
```

And replacement is unlikely to change, just use `""`

`clean` is now simpler:

```
public static string clean(string s) 
{
    return Regex.Replace(s, cleaner, "").ToLower();
}
```

Variables should be declared in the smallest possible scope, so putting the pattern inside the function is best. @Mat's Mug suggests inlining it, and I agree for such small a pattern.

**Avoid unnecessary variables**

```
bool isPalindrome = IsPalindrome(mergedLine);
```

Delete that line, just use:

```
Console.WriteLine(isPalindrome(mergedLine) ? "Palindrome" : "Not a palindrome");
```

Also isPalindrome can use less verbose names and be reduced to:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string someString)
{
    var cleaned = clean(someString);
    return cleaned.Equals(amendedString.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Seriously reducing noise.

**Single responsibility system**

@t3chb0t rightfully noted that `isPalindrome` still does two things, in fact, it is better to implement it like:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string text)
{
    return text.Equals(text.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

And be careful to pass in cleaned strings.
Now it really does only one thing.

Comment: I think `IsPalindrome` shouldn't clean the string, it should be passed a cleaned one otherwise you have again two things that this method does. Also I would use the helper variable `isPalindrome` for the sake of easier debugging ;-) perhaps not necessarily in this case but it's a good habit.

Comment: @t3chb0t _I think IsPalindrome shouldn't clean the string_ -> True. _Also I would use the helper variable isPalindrome for the sake of easier debugging_ -> You say when using the debugger, allowing you see all the values of all the variables? I have no experience using that, but code should not be bloated forever for debugging that may only happen once.